# Empty html tag <tr>elements vba

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I am scraping through a website and it has a tag

```
<tr>
  <td></d>
</tr>
```

I loop through the page and it gets to the empty  child  and error comes up "object required" How can I get around the tag. I tried an if statement using `IE.document.getelementsbyTagName("tr")(icount).children(0) = " "`.... but it did not work. Please advise me on how to deal with this.

Comment: Please poste the code

Comment: We need to see more of the surrounding code. You could probably use `Set` to use a variable instead of accessing the `children` property directly - then you could check to see if the variable is `Nothing` before using it.

Answer (score 0):

Though I don't really recommend it, you could do the following:

```
On Error Resume Next
```

to skip the line, then test the variable to find out if a value was assigned.  I am certain there is a better way do it, but it depends on how you are parsing the data.

You can also do some real error handling, which is a good idea anyway:

```
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
```

Then at the bottom of the subroutine (or function) you would put

```
Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    //Do something...
    Resume
End Sub
```

Comment: you may also want to check out articles on parsing html/xml in vba:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29525064/ms-access-vba-parse-xml-file

Comment: The value is nothing I MsgBox it out and it was blank. I don't know any other way in dealing with. On the error resume next is there a way to place it in an if statement so on the error I can exit the loop

Comment: With either of the solutions above, you will have to test the variable value to find out if you need to exit the loop (if IsNull(Variable) then exit for) something like that